# How can I find stocks with highly priced option premiums?

Tags: stocks, options, premiums

I'm trying to learn some basic arbitrage and I'm reading about tons of different strategies, but it looks as though option premiums are often less than $0.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for options with distant expiration dates and volatile underlying stocks.

Comment: Fantastic. Are there option charts for various strike prices like stock charts?

Comment: The NASDAQ website has options charts

Comment: so does yahoo: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=IBM+Options

Answer (score 1):

Options are priced pretty close to the [Black–Scholes model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes). The key factors are the current stock price, strike price, time to expiration, the risk-free rate of return, and most important, the stock volatility. I say the volatility is most important as all other variables are pretty static, the thing differentiating two $50 stocks is volatility.

Not knowing your actual goal, I'm not sure what else to offer. As James stated, the premium will rise for options that have longer til expiration.

Comment: This is interesting.  I posted a related question here:  http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8898/does-the-black-scholes-model-apply-to-american-style-options